# SQL create empty table and fill some rows with info

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

Is it possible to create an empty table with a fixed number of rows (the number is defined in another table) and defined columns(col1 and col2) and then replace some of the rows in this empty table with the ones I get from a select?

I want the final structure to be like this :

```
col1        col2
----------------
empty       empty
val11       val21
val12       val22
empty       empty
val13       val23
empty       empty
```

where I take val11, val21.... from another select. I want this table with empty values to be only local aka not create it anywhere else.

Comment: There is no internal row order in Oracle (or any other major RDBMS), so you might as well just insert the rows you want followed by rows containing null.

Comment: I usually use the connect by level trick to make empty rows when I need them, here is one for 10 rows.    select level as id, null as col1, null as col2 from dual connect by level <= 10

Comment: Why would you want blank rows in the first place?

Comment: @Boneist because that's how I want them to be displayed on screen in a Listbox, in a ZK application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a table with a variable number (say 5) of rows with empty fields;
about the ordering, you can not use any internal ordering, so you need to add a field to hold the position of the row.
For example:

```
SQL> create table tab_5(id number, col1 varchar2(50), col2 varchar2(50))
  2  /

Table created.

SQL> insert into tab_5
  2  select level, null, null
  3  from dual
  4  connect by level <= 5
  5  /

5 rows created.


SQL> select * from tab_5 order by id;

        ID COL1                 COL2
---------- -------------------- --------------------
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5
```

If you need to update some records in interlaced way, you can rely on your id

```
SQL> update tab_5
  2  set col1 = 'something',
  3      col2 = 'something else'
  4  where mod(id, 2) = 0;

2 rows updated.

SQL> select * from tab_5 order by id;

        ID COL1                 COL2
---------- -------------------- --------------------
         1
         2 something            something else
         3
         4 something            something else
         5

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any point in inserting a fixed number of empty records only to "replace" them later.  Rather, a better idea would be to just `INSERT` the records you want and then add some null records afterwards.

First `INSERT` the records you want from the other table:

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (col1, col2)
SELECT col1, col2
FROM anotherTable
```

Then `INSERT` the "empty" records:

```
INSERT ALL
INTO yourTable (col1, col2) VALUES (null, null)
INTO yourTable (col1, col2) VALUES (null, null)
INTO yourTable (col1, col2) VALUES (null, null)
...
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: I need them to be interlaced (empty with non empty ones) and as I said, I need a fixed number, let's say 27 rows. But this number, 27, might change on subsequent calls, based on some values I get from another table. I'm not looking for efficiency, I'm looking for something to work.

Comment: There is no concept of "interlaced," at least not internally in the Oracle database.  If you want a certain order then let us know what that order is.